# Warning: "Viewport argument value "100%" for key "width" was truncated to its numeric prefix."

Tags: css, html, warnings, viewport

I have this line in my `.html` file:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

And I am getting this warning in Chrome:

Viewport argument value `"100%"` for key "width" was truncated to its numeric prefix.

How to fix it?

Comment: are you using the XHTML ending /> on purpose? seems like an odd thing together with the viewport-meta-tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should this not be something like

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

BTW these:

```
maximum-scale=1
user-scalable=no
```

are generally considered as providing a poor user experience.